# ASP.NET MVC 3 Simple Scenario Authorization for Static Files

Tags: asp.net, security

Let's say I have a really simple site where I allow registered users to upload files.  I have user "andrew" with an ID of 1 and user "matt" with and ID of 2.

Let's say I want to use the following folder structure to organize the uploaded files.

```
/Content/DocRepo/[[ID]]/files_live_here
```

I am using forms authentication so I could use the web config location element to prevent any unauthorized users from access the DocRepo, however once "andrew" is logged in, what is the cleanest/simplest way to prevent him from accessing "matt's" files?

Couldn't he just change the URL to `/Content/DocRepo/2/`

Comment: First step could be to use a GUID instead of the ID. Then you will need to secure each request beyond that if you need mroe

Comment: @aherrick have you found a solution for this? can you please share the sample code here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is not to allow direct requests to the files at all. Prevent requests to the files directory, and instead create a files controller which requires Auth, and assures a user has access to the file they are requesting.

You can use a subdirectory of `App_Data` to store the files, since by default, no direct requests can be made for any files contained therein.

Comment: Upon thinking about it, I agree this is the proper solution.

Comment: Hey thanks that makes sense... Would I want to try and prevent requests to the /Content/DocRepo/ folder by using some kind of custom route?

Comment: The problem with the web config setting is that it uses forms authentication and attempts to redirect them to a /login page.  I don't want to do that necessarily.  I would want to

Comment: @aherrick Oh, duh! I'm forgetting an obvious option: if you could store the files in a subdirectory of App_Data; that directory by default can not have files directly requested.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but I'm trying to think through solution where I don't have access to IIS 7 settings OR have the ability to host the files outside of the web root...  as in like a deployment on AppHarbor

Comment: @aherrick right; App_Data is really the right answer to that. It exists and is configured pretty much (in part) exactly for this kind of thing.

Comment: actually I think app_data storage would meet all my requirements!

Comment: do you have a sample code for file controller to access files from app_data ?

Answer (score 2):

It could be done in the Global.asax under the Application_AuthenticateRequest or the Application_BeginRequest. You could also register a IHTTPHandeler and do the same logic as the Global.asax, which would be to listen to requests for the DocRepo folder and perform user permission audits.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can easily create a Download action on your controller that accepts some sort of file ID and do your validation there. If you're using classic ASP.NET would make a page, download.aspx which takes some unique ID (both as Andrew suggested).

In MVC you can add an Authorize filter to the action to allow only authenticated users and from there you can do per-user level checking. In MVC there is a File result:

```
 return File(...);
```

Comment: Those would work. I suggested the controller since he is already using mvc. +1 for other options, anyway!

Comment: He didnt specify he was using MVC, I've updated my answer to include MVC as an option. I guess we could assume MVC from the URL structure as a route.

Comment: He said it was mvc3 in the title.